# Merge two loops and Sort by date in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<div class="transaction-list">
<!-- START 1ST LOOP -->
<?php
    foreach($transaction_list_buy as $transaction) {
?> 
    <div class="transaction-item px-4 py-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#P<?php echo $transaction->deal_id; ?>">
        <div class="row align-items-center flex-row">
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-1 text-center d-none d-sm-block"> <span class="d-block text-4 font-weight-300"><?php $date=date_create($transaction->deal_datetime); echo date_format($date,"d"); ?></span> <span class="d-block text-1 font-weight-300 text-uppercase"><?php $date=date_create($transaction->deal_datetime); echo date_format($date,"M"); ?></span> </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-7"> <span class="d-block text-4"><?php echo $transaction->deal_id; ?></span> <span class="text-muted">
            <?php 
                    if($transaction->deal_status==0) {
                        echo "Buyer Initiated";
                } else if($transaction->deal_status==1) {
                    echo "Prepay Verified Deal";
                } else if($transaction->deal_status==2) {
                    echo "Seller Confirmed";
                } else if($transaction->deal_status==3) {
                    echo "Buyer Received";
                } else if($transaction->deal_status==4) {
                    echo "Seller Claimed";
                } else if($transaction->deal_status==5) {
                    echo "Prepay Released Payment";
                } else if($transaction->deal_status==6) {
                    echo "Buyer Cancelled";
                }else if($transaction->deal_status==7) {
                    echo "Prepay Dropped";
                }?>
            </span> </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 text-center text-3"> <span class="text-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Payment Verified"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></span> </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 text-right text-4"> <span class="text-2 text-uppercase">RM</span> <span class="text-nowrap"><?php echo number_format($transaction->payment_amount, 2, '.', ''); ?></span> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
<!-- START 2ND LOOP -->
<?php
    foreach($transaction_list_sell as $transaction) {
?> 
    <div class="transaction-item px-4 py-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#P<?php echo $transaction->deal_id; ?>">
        <div class="row align-items-center flex-row">
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-1 text-center d-none d-sm-block"> <span class="d-block text-4 font-weight-300"><?php $date=date_create($transaction->deal_datetime); echo date_format($date,"d"); ?></span> <span class="d-block text-1 font-weight-300 text-uppercase"><?php $date=date_create($transaction->deal_datetime); echo date_format($date,"M"); ?></span> </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-7"> <span class="d-block text-4"><?php echo $transaction->deal_id; ?></span> <span class="text-muted">
            <?php 
                    if($transaction->deal_status==0) {
                        echo "Buyer Initiated";
                } else if($transaction->deal_status==1) {
                    echo "Prepay Verified Deal";
                } else if($transaction->deal_status==2) {
                    echo "Seller Confirmed";
                } else if($transaction->deal_status==3) {
                    echo "Buyer Received";
                } else if($transaction->deal_status==4) {
                    echo "Seller Claimed";
                } else if($transaction->deal_status==5) {
                    echo "Prepay Released Payment";
                } else if($transaction->deal_status==6) {
                    echo "Buyer Cancelled";
                }else if($transaction->deal_status==7) {
                    echo "Prepay Dropped";
                }?>
            </span> </div>
            <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 text-center text-3"> <span class="text-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Payment Verified"><i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i></span> </div>
            <div class="col-3 col-sm-2 text-right text-4"> <span class="text-2 text-uppercase">RM</span> <span class="text-nowrap"><?php echo number_format($transaction->payment_amount, 2, '.', ''); ?></span> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>                              
</div>
```

Just the same structure of data.
Different is buy(1st) and sell(2nd).

Based on current code, the data will be printed from completed first loop, then 2nd loop will start.
The issue here is,both contain date & **i would like to merge these two and by sorting them based on newest/latest date at top.**

Currently, the loop will start from oldest.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your expected outcome, but as a side note, do something about your code duplication... You could think about using a _function_, which you feed the array you want to parse (i.e. `$transaction_list_buy` or `$transaction_list_sell`).

Comment: Also, you can drop the nested `if` / `elseif` block inside your function with something more concise like: `$status = ['Buyer Initiated', 'Prepay Verified Deal', 'Seller Confirmed', 'Buyer Received', 'Seller Claimed', 'Prepay Released Payment', 'Buyer Cancelled', 'Prepay Dropped'];` `echo $status[$transaction->deal_status];`

Answer (score 0):

Do the merge before you output anything.

Iterate both the transaction lists and add their items to a new array using the datetime as the key. You may need to convert `$datetime` to a sortable format like Y-m-d or timestamp if it is not already.

```
foreach ([$transaction_list_buy, $transaction_list_sell] as $list) {
    foreach ($list as $transaction) {
        $datetime = $transaction->deal_datetime;
        // reformat $datetime if it is not sortable

        $merged[$datetime][] = $transaction; // append rather than assign
    }
}
```

Each datetime should contain an array of transactions. If we set a single value like `$merged[$datetime] = $transaction;` instead of `$merged[$datetime][] = $transaction;` then we would potentially overwrite values if some transactions had the same datetime value.

Then you can sort by key and output the sorted list:

```
krsort($merged);

foreach ($merged as $datetime => $transactions) {
    foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
        // output transaction
    }
}
```

---

Not related to the merge/sort, but you might consider storing the status strings in an array. Then you could just do

```
echo $status_string[$transaction->deal_status];
```

instead of all those else ifs.

Comment: Or, write a query that returns both "buys" and "sells" sorted by date.

Comment: @DFriend good point. Doing this kind of thing in the database is almost always better if you are able to.

Comment: Will try this. Currently the query from db separated buy and sell as u can see above.

Answer (score 0):

its ok.
found easiest way.
just do query for buy OR sell.
then sort by date desc